# Random white column to the right of web page

Tags: html, css

I am currently using HTML and CSS to modify my library's libguides2 homepage.  For some reason there is a phantom white column that is showing up on the right side of the page.  It's there in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.  It does NOT show up on IE.  It doesn't show up when the page loads, but if you scroll to the right on desktop or zoom out on mobile, there it is.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Here's the live site:

http://nybg.beta.libguides.com/

And here's my fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/pjp5rxws/

The white space isn't in the fiddle, but Springshare support (the people who make and host libguides) says that it's not something in the code for the page that I can't get at.

Any ideas?  This issue is not the end of the world, but I would like to understand and fix it if possible!

And I know that my css should be in a separate document although it is not yet in a separate document--the site is set up in such a way that this is how I am managing my beta version for the time being. I do plan to move the css!

I'm not sure what of my code is helpful here, so here is my css:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  - moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*:after,
*:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}
html {
  font-size: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
.clear {
  display: block;
}
.clear::after {
  clear: both;
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
mobilenav {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
}
mobilenav div {
  width: 100%;
}
mobilenav a {
  color: #ffffff;
  letter-spacing: 0.0625em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem;
}
mobilenav a:hover {
  color: #DADADA;
  text-decoration: none;
}
mobilenav > nav > ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
mobilenav > nav > ul:hover {
  background-color: #000000;
}
mobilenav > nav > ul > li {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all linear 0.1s;
}
mobilenav > nav > ul > li a + div {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
mobilenav > nav > ul > li:hover a + div {
  display: block;
  background-color: #000000;
}
mobilenav > nav > ul > li a + div > ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
mobilenav > nav > ul > li a + div > ul > li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
mobilenav > nav > ul > li a + div > ul > li > a {
  display: block;
  padding: .25rem 1.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}
mobilenav > nav > ul > li > a {
  align-items: flex-start;
  display: flex;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  padding: 1% 0;
}
.headerimage {
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 2%;
}
.headerimage img {
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 50px;
}
.logoname {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  flex-flow: row;
}
.fullpage {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.menu {
  background-color: #000000;
}
.site-navigation ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.site-navigation a {
  color: #ffffff;
  letter-spacing: 0.0625em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem;
}
.site-navigation a:hover {
  color: #DADADA;
}
.fullpagesnh {
  background: url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/libapps/accounts/69823/images/IVO_2541_LARGE.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
.fullpagesnh h2 {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.fullpagesnh a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.fullpagesnh a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.snhcontainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.searchandhours {
  flex-direction: row;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.librarysearch {
  margin: 100px 0 100px 0;
  padding: 20px;
}
.fullpagesnh form {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
}
.hours ul {
  padding: 20px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  color: #ffffff;
  list-style: none;
}
.contentcontainer {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding-top: 100px;
}
.row {
  display: inline-block;
}
.sideblack {
  margin: 5% 2.5%;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: larger;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.sideblack:hover {
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.Special_box {
  margin: 5% 2.5%;
  border: 1px solid #CECECE;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
.Special_box h2 {
  color: #000000;
}
.Special_box p {
  color: #999AA9;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.Special_box:hover {
  background-color: #CECECE;
}
.Special_box a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.Special_box .bottom {
  padding: 10px;
}
.Special_box img {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.libguidescontent .row {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.nav.nav-pills button.btn {
  background-color: #ffffff !important;
  color: #000000 !important;
}
.libguidescontent .alert {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  border: none;
}
.libguidescontent h1 {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}
.libguidescontent a {
  color: #000000;
}
.libguidescontent strong {
  color: #26B56E;
}
.whitespace {
  height: 200px;
}
.footfoot {
  background-color: #000000;
}
.foot-navigation ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.foot-navigation ul li {
  padding-right: 50px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.foot-navigation ul li h3 {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .Special_box img {
    display: none;
  }
  .sideblack {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
  mobilenav {
    display: block;
  }
  .contentcontainer {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .headerimage img {
    width: 200px;
    padding-right: 30px;
  }
  .headerimage h1 {
    font-size: 14px;
    word-wrap: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
  }
  .site-navigation ul {
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .foot-navigation ul {
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    padding-left: 20px;
  }
  .searchandhours {
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    padding-left: 20px;
  }
  .librarysearch {
    margin: 0;
  }
  .libraryhours {
    display: none;
  }
  body {
    margin: 0;
  }
  .menu {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: And I know that my css should be in a separate document although it is not yet in a separate document--the site is set up in such a way that this is how I am managing my beta version for the time being.  I do plan to move the css!

Comment: I can ONLY reproduce your issue on your live site in Chrome if I scroll to the right

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in latest chrome on mac. What are you using?

Comment: @SergChernata - you CAN scroll to the right to see the issue, but on load the page seems to fill the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the margin for row solved the issue.

[image: Chrome Dev Tools]

See Attached for reference.

Answer (score 3):

In your `.contentcontainer` div, you have multiple `.row` elements with negative left and right margins :

```
.row {
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
```

You might want to give your `.contentcontainer` some padding of the opposite value :

```
.contentcontainer {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

add that to the css of the html

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: I did attempt this, but then I wasn't able to scroll at all.  It was very odd.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much, all!  Many good solutions.  Here is another I got back from the Springshare Lounge group:

Hi Esther,

It looks like the main section of your page is using Bootstrap columns (the part in ). However, it's not in a container or container-fluid, so the appropriate sizing isn't being applied. I'd suggest changing your code just a tiny bit:

```
<div class="contentcontainer container-fluid">
<div class="departmentbuttons">
```

That should do it!

Best,
Carrie, Springshare Support